# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) in /wp-content/themes/awaken/page.php on line 26

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing

i have error log

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) in
>   /wp-content/themes/awaken/page.php
>   on line 26

my page.php

```
get_header(); ?>
<div class="row">
<?php is_rtl() ? $rtl = 'awaken-rtl' : $rtl = ''; ?>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 <?php echo $rtl ?>">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
                <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'display_page_comments', 1 ) ) { // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) : comments_template(); endif; } ?>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- .bootstrap cols -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- .bootstrap cols -->
</div><!-- .row -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Please help!
i have a 503 error, and think it's a problem

Comment: <?php endwhile; /* end of the loop.*/ ?>

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix regular and extended syntax, especially when you've got horrible indenting. Note how the code looks **WITHOUT** all the repetitive/pointless php open/close tags:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   if ( get_theme_mod( 'display_page_comments', 1 ) ) { // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) : comments_template(); endif; }
      endwhile; // end of the loop
```

since you commented out part of the `if`, you never close the `{`, which means your endwhile is trying to terminate a while which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see it? I do. You've commented out code and incidentally took the closing bracket to `if( get_theme_mod` with it. This is a simple syntax error.

```
<?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'display_page_comments', 1 ) ) { // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) : comments_template(); endif; } ?>
```

Needs to be changed to

```
 <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'display_page_comments', 1 ) ) { 
     // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template 
     if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) : 
         comments_template();        
     endif; 
 } ?>
```

If you don't want the comments template, then just comment out `//comments_template();`

The reason for this is that the inline commenting you've added will comment out the entire `line` it doesn't pick and choose which parts it should comment out and which parts it should let the interpreter process.